# Автоматический секундомер при заходе на любой сайт

Tags: браузер, плагин

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста программу или расширения для браузеров которая при заходе на любой сайт начинает автоматически вести отчет времени, то есть зашли на сайт, сразу же пошел таймер секунд сколько вы пробыли на нём, перешли на другой сайт - там так же сразу открывается таймер времени и т.д.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А при переходе на другой сайт предыдущий таймер останавливается или сбрасывается?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».